# How is the javascript packer using "void 0"?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm looking at somebody's javascript code that is minimized and I see a syntax that doesn't make any sense.

```
firstObject.init = function() {
  void 0 === secondObject.properties && thirsObject.reportError("Something is wrong");
  firstObject.doSomething();
}
```

My guess is that packer is checking for an undefined property, breaking out of the execution context and returning null in that case.

```
if (secondObject.properties === undefined) {
  thirdObject.reportError("Something is wrong");
  return NULL;
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Aside from the `return NULL;`, your guess is exactly what that line does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the result of `void 0` it quickly becomes clear what's happening:

```
> void 0
undefined
```

Therefore, writing

```
void 0 === secondObject.properties
```

is simply a different way of writing

```
typeof secondObject.properties === "undefined"
```

---

> Does this end the execution of the function or simply continues after executing the code to the right of the && operator?

Condition evaluation is usually <del>lazy</del> "short-circuit", that is, if it is already certain that a condition will evaluate to true or false, further sub-conditions are not evaluated anymore. For example:

```
false && alert("foo"); // Will never alert foo
true && alert("foo"); // Will always alert foo
```

If you have any two conditions combined by a `&&` operator, if the first (left) condition is false, the entire condition will be false no matter the it's value. Therefore, evaluation of the second condition is not necessary, and thus discarded.

#### More information:

- <del>[Lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) on Wikipedia</del>
- [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: Does this end the execution of the function or simply continues after executing the code to the right of the && operator?

Comment: Edited my answer to address your question :)

Comment: It's **not** lazy evaluation, but [short-circuit evalution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)!

Comment: Please use the `void` keyword without parenthesis, it's not a function.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for correcting me, I didn't know about the term "short-circuit evaluation". It seems to me however, that short-circuit evaluation is actually a subset of lazy evaluation which has been ported from truly "lazy" programming languages such as haskell to languages that do not operate that way by default, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I'm not sure about the history of languages, but I think it's more like having a control structure hidden in the operator.